# Recognize mod-folds

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

## Task

Define a *mod-fold* as a function of the form **f(x) = x % a<sub>1</sub> % a<sub>2</sub> % … % a<sub>k</sub>**, where the **a<sub>i</sub>** are positive integers and **k ≥ 0**. (Here, **%** is the left-associative modulo operator.)

Given a list of **n** integers **y<sub>0</sub>, …, y<sub>n−1</sub>**,  determine if there exists a mod-fold **f** so that each **y<sub>i</sub> = f(i)**.

You may choose and fix **any two outputs** *Y* and *N* for your function/program. If there exists such an **f**, you must always return/print exactly *Y*; if not, you must always return/print exactly *N*. (These could be `true`/`false`, or `1`/`0`, or `false`/`true`, etc.) Mention these in your answer.

The shortest submission in bytes wins.

## Example

Define **f(x) = x % 7 % 3**. Its values start:

```
|   x  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | ...
| f(x) | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | ...
```

Thus, given `0 1 2 0 1 2 0 0 1 2` as input to our solution, we would print *Y*, as this **f** generates that sequence. However, given `0 1 0 1 2` as input, we would print *N*, as no **f** generates that sequence.

## Test cases

The formulas given when the output is *Y* are just for reference; you must at no point print them.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5              Y    (x)
1                        N
0 0 0                    Y    (x%1)
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 0 1 2      Y    (x%7%3)
0 0 1                    N
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 1 2    Y    (x%8%7)
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 3      N
0 2 1 0 2 1 0 2 1        N
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1    Y    (x%9%4%3%2)
```

Comment: Are there any time or memory limits?

Comment: Can I output truthy values and falsey values instead?

Comment: @Leaky I'd rather you not. I'm not a big fan of truthy-falsey; I'm explicitly trying this as a more objective alternative that still gives you freedom.

Comment: @Lynn is it just me or you still haven't fixed it?

Comment: Regarding memory/time constraints: I don't think I'll add any to the challenge itself, but I might run a bounty for the shortest answer in bytes that can answer each one of my test cases in some reasonable time length.

Comment: @LeakyNun FYI, I changed the sequence instead of correcting the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
}Qm%M+RdUQy_Sl
```

Returns `True/False`. Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7DQm%25M%2BRdUQy_Sl&input=%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2%5D&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%2C0%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C3%5D%0A%5B0%2C2%2C1%2C0%2C2%2C1%2C0%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7DQm%25M%2BRdUQy_Sl&input=%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%2C0%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C3%5D%0A%5B0%2C2%2C1%2C0%2C2%2C1%2C0%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
}Qm%M+RdUQy_SlQ   implicit Q (=input) at the end
             lQ   length of input list
            S     create the list [1, 2, ..., len]
           _      reverse => [len, ..., 2, 1]
          y       generate all subsets (these are all possible mod-folds)
  m               map each subset d to:
        UQ           take the range [0, 1, ..., len-1]
     +Rd             transform each number into a list by prepending it to d
                     e.g. if mod-fold = [7,3], than it creates:
                        [[0,7,3], [1,7,3], [2,7,3], [3,7,3], ...]
   %M                fold each list by the modulo operator
                  this gives all possible truthy sequences of length len
}Q                so checking if Q appears in the list returns True or False
```

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
q%M.e+k_tx0
```

Based on [@ferrsum's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85580/29577). I actually thought about using the zero-indices for the subset generation, but didn't realize, that all zero-indices has to be the solution already.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>239</s> 218 bytes

```
from itertools import*
lambda z:z in[[eval(''.join([str(l)]+['%'+str(i[::-1][k])for k in range(len(i))]))for l in range(len(z))]for i in(i for j in(combinations(range(1,len(z)+1),i+1)for i in range(len(z)))for i in j)]
```

An anonymous function that takes input of a list `z` and returns `True` or `False` for `Y` and `N`.

This uses a method similar to @Jakube 's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85554/55526), and although it is essentially a brute force, runs very quickly.

```
from itertools import*               Import everything from the Python module for
                                     iterable generation
lambda z                             Anonymous function with input list z
combinations(range(1,len(z)+1),i+1)  Yield all sorted i+1 length subsets of the range
                                     [1,len(z)]...
...for i in range(len(z))            ...for all possible subset lengths
(i for j in(...)for i in j)          Flatten, yielding an iterator containing all possible
                                     mod-fold values as separate lists
...for i in...                       For all possible mod-fold values...
...for k in range(len(i))            ...for all mod-fold values indices k...
...for l in range(len(z))            ...for all function domain values in [0,len(z)-1]...
[str(l)]+['%'+str(i[::-1][k])...]    ...create a list containing each character of the
                                     expression representing the function defined by the
                                     mod-fold values (reversed such that the divisors
                                     decrease in magnitude) applied to the domain value...
 eval(''.join(...))                  ...concatenate to string and evaluate...
 [...]                               ...and pack all the values for that particular
                                     function as a list
 [...]                               Pack all lists representing all functions into a list
 ...:z in...                         If z is in this list, it must be a valid mod-fold, so
                                     return True. Else, return False
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/71cO7I)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 69 bytes

```py
f=lambda a,i=0:i/len(a)or a[i]in[a[i-1]+1,i,0][i<=max(a)::2]*f(a,i+1)
```

Uses `True`/`False`.

The answer to what characterizes a mod-foldable series turns out to be less interesting than it seems at first. It is a series of the form 0, 1, ..., M - 1, 0, 1, ... x<sub>1</sub>, 0, 1, ..., x<sub>2</sub>, ... such that for all i, 0 <= x<sub>i</sub> < M. Such a sequence can be produced by the mod chain of all the (0-based) indices of the zeroes in the array, excluding the first.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>19</s> <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
LṗLUZ’1¦%/sLe@
```

Returns **1** for truthy, **0** for falsy. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=TOG5l0xVWuKAmTHCpiUvc0xlQA&input=&args=WzAsIDEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVd)

The algorithm is **O(n<sup>n</sup>)**, where **n** is the length of the list, making it too slow and memory-intensive for most of the test cases.

A modified version – which replaces the second `L` with a `5` – can be used to [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=TOG5lzVVWuKAmTHCpiUvc0xlQArDh-KCrEc&input=&args=WzAsMSwyLDMsNCw1XSwgWzFdLCBbMCwwLDBdLCBbMCwxLDIsMCwxLDIsMCwwLDEsMl0sIFswLDAsMV0sIFswLDEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDAsMCwxLDJdLCBbMCwxLDIsMCwxLDIsMCwxLDIsM10sIFswLDIsMSwwLDIsMSwwLDIsMV0sIFswLDEsMCwwLDAsMSwwLDAsMCwwLDFd). Note that this modified version won't work for arbitrarily long lists.

#### How it works

```
LṗLUZ’1¦%/sLe@  Main link. Argument: A (array of integers)

L L             Yield the length l of A.
 ṗ              Take the l-th Cartesian power of [1, ..., l], i.e., construct
                all arrays of length l that consist of elements of [1, ..., l].
   U            Upend/reverse each array. This way, the first l arrays start
                with [1, ..., l], as do the next l arrays, etc.
    Z           Zip/transpose the array of arrays.
     ’1¦        Decrement the first array to map [1, ..., l] to [0, ..., l - 1].
        %/      Reduce the array's columns by modulus/residue.
          sL    Split the result into chunks of length l.
            e@  Verify if A belongs to the resulting array.
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?  As someone who hasn't used Jelly (yet), I have no idea how it works.

Comment: I'll add one as soon as I'm done golfing. There still are a few things I want to try first.

Comment: I've (given up and) added an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>98</s> bytes

```
a=>a.every((n,i)=>n?n<(l+=p==i)&&n==p++:p=1,l=p=1)
```

Saved 48 bytes by switching to @Feersum's discovery. Any given value `n` in the array is either zero, in which case the next prediction `p` is 1, or it equals the next prediction, in which case `p` is incremented. We also measure the length `l` of the initial sequence by comparing `p` to `i`, as `n` must always be less than `l` at all times.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>103</s> 99 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,r:r==x or l and f(l-1,[t%l for t in r])|f(l-1,r)
x=input();l=len(x);print+f(l,range(l))
```

Prints **1** for truthy and **0** for falsy. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/62bluK).